# Optimal image transformation using cloudinary

Tags: android, android-layout, cloudinary

I am new to android and developing an online food delivery application.

I want to use cloudinary to store images so that I can transform them to different sizes easily and can display it on app for better look and feel.

So my question is- in which format, pixel and size of image should upload on cloudinary so that after transformation it won't get much distorted and final size of image should be in few KBs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, because we don't know how you're app will be looking and where the images are placed. _But_ it is a common practice to store the _same_ image in multiple resolutions to support different devices. You can read aout this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to upload the original image to Cloudinary as-is and then deliver the transformed images.
For example, this is the original sample image - 
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg

Transforming it to a 100X100 on-the-fly - 
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_100,h_100,c_fill/sample.jpg

You can also perform the transformations eagerly (to be available immediately)  - 
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#eager_transformations